# BASH - how to make this always running from system boot and on crash restart?

Tags: linux, bash, centos

I have this protocol port open to read remotely from Python, PHP applications but daily it crash and the port is unavailable as a result Python, PHP all client application fails

```
$ cat /var/tmp/server.sh
#!/bin/bash
while true; do tail -f /usr/local/freeswitch/log/freeswitch.log | nc -l -p 9999 -q 1 &
```

Q. Is there anyway to make this script always running like `service this start or stop` and if its crashed that somehow it automatically again get restarted ? Any advise or link to do such thing? i am using CentOS 6.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your script in `/etc/inittab` as following

```
id:1:respawn:/var/tmp/server.sh
```

Refer to http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl5_inittab.htm for more information about the `/etc/initab` file.

After editing `/etc/inittab` restart your system.